# Problems with the discord.py bot

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have a problem and it is that when someone who is not admin and executes the command '/ cls' the bot does not send the message that it should and what it does is give me an error in the cmd.

I add the code.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def cls(ctx, Quantity= 10000):
    if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=Quantity)
        await ctx.send('Successful removal!' + Quantity + ' mensajes.')
    else: 
        await ctx.send('You cannot run the '/cls' command because you are not admin')
```

This is what the cmd tells me when someone executes the command '/ cls' and what I want is that it gives the message that I put there.

discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingPermissions: You are missing Manage Messages permission(s) to run this command.

Comment: by the way, the max messages you can bulk delete is 200 at a time. So 10k is waay too much

Comment: thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `has_permissions` check

Below is the revised code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def cls(ctx, Quantity= 10000):
    if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(Quantity))
        await ctx.send('Successful removal!' + Quantity + ' mensajes.')
    else: 
        await ctx.send('You cannot run the '/cls' command because you are not admin')
```

Comment: Thank you for the time it took you to answer this question, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what **Poojan** suggested or you can simply pass two permissions in the `has_permissions` decorator.

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True, manage_messages=True)
async def cls(ctx, quantity: int=10000): # I'm typehinting the quantity so it's already passed as an integer
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=quantity) 
    await ctx.send("Succesful removal of {quantity} messages")


# If you want to send some message when the user doesn't have the needed perms:
@cls.error
async def cls_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f"You need {error.missing_perms} to use this command")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("Please use only numbers")
```

Comment: Thank you for the time it took you to answer this question, you helped me a lot.

Comment: No worries, you can return me a favor by accepting and upvoting the answer.